# Need help in making a fit to my experimental data

Tags: data

This is what I have done so far. The points are of angles-of-deviation and wavelengths from my physics lab experiment.

```
V = ListPlot[
  {{589.3, 53.50}, {435.8, 56.02}, {535.4, 54.52}, {546.1, 
    53.57}, {577.0, 53.13}, {690.9, 52.10}, {402.6, 55.72}, {447.2, 
    55.02}, {492.2, 54.53}, {501.6, 54.83}, {587.6, 53.03}, {667.8, 
    52.83}, {706.5, 52.05}
   }, PlotRange -> {{400, 710}, {50, 60}}, 
  AxesLabel -> { wavelength, deviation}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image: this is what i have done so far.]

I am trying to find the best fit line of these points. I know it is some type of exponential function. But I can not figure out how to do it. Please help me out.

Comment: The relation appears to be linear.  Why not use regression?

Comment: Which is the dependent and which is the independent variable (or are both independent)? Regression of y with respect to x is not the same as regression of x with respect to y.

Comment: @geordie.  Very good point. That makes me suspect that the (linear) Fit that I used below works differently from regression.

Comment: @geordie If the experiment is to calibrate one set of measurements to the other, as taya suggests in a comment to dwa, then the standard measure would presumably correspond the dependent variable.

Comment: @DavidCarraher. Given the scatter in both x and y, it seems reasonable to assume there is an uncertainty associated with each measurement - in which case a simple linear regression (least squares, etc.) will produce an unreliable fit. Better methods are available using [robust stats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_regression). Then again, perhaps I'm over thinking this...

Comment: Didn't know about robust stats.  Btw, there is very little scatter.  The Pearson correlation is -.96

Comment: @DavidCarraher. I have to be more careful with my choice of words... the points seem irregularly sampled (not scattered) implying that there is an uncertainty in both x and y. Now I am definitely over thinking this..

Answer (score 2):

Given the distribution of the data, you should use linear model, unless you have compelling theoretical reasons for believing the model is not linear.

```
data = {{589.3, 53.50}, {435.8, 56.02}, {535.4, 54.52}, {546.1, 53.57}, {577.0, 53.13},{690.9, 52.10}, {402.6, 55.72}, {447.2, 55.02}, {492.2, 54.53}, {501.6, 54.83}, {587.6,53.03}, {667.8, 52.83}, {706.5, 52.05}};
Show[
  ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{400, 710}, {50, 60}}, AxesLabel -> {"wavelength", "deviation"}, 
    PlotStyle -> Red, GridLines -> Automatic], 
  Plot[Evaluate@Fit[data, {1, x}, x], {x, 400, 710}]
     ]
```

[image: linear]

Comment: The Dungeon Master told them it's an exponential. That's what I call a compelling experimental reason.

Comment: @belisarius hits the evil dungeon master with his comment of snarkiness +1?

Comment: @bobthechemist It was with the hammer of cynicism (+1 to hit, +3 damage)

Answer (score 0):

It's straightforward, and can get gleaned from the documentation.

After `Sort@data`,

```
nfit = NonlinearModelFit[data, a Exp[-t/\[Tau]], {a, \[Tau]}, t]
nfit["AdjustedRSquared"]
Show[{V,
  Plot[nfit[t], {t, 400, 710}]
  }
 ]
```

will compare your experimental data to an exponential fit.  Documentation on `NonlinearModelFit` gets you a bunch of diagnostics.

Having said that, after looking at `\[Tau]`, why not fit a linear function?

Comment: in the lab hand out, the professor gave the example graph that the calibration curve should resemble a curve line,,, which i guess it some kind of exponential...

Comment: I see no reason to sort the data. Am I missing something.

Comment: No compelling reason, since NonlinearModelFit appears to handle data 'as is'.